# REACT can't do object assign in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I got a problem when do objectAssign to change the state in store into a new data from server, It always get a null as the result.

i call my action in onEnter function(React-Router)

```
export function GET_SetupTabTitles() {
    store.dispatch(getSetupTabTitles());
}
```

this is my action :

```
import {
    TOGGLE_DRAWER_IN_APPBAR,
    GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES,
} from '../constants/actionTypes';

import axios from 'axios';
const ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';

export function toggleDrawerInAppBar(open){
    return { type: TOGGLE_DRAWER_IN_APPBAR, openStatus: open }
}

export function getSetupTabTitles(){
    return function(dispatch){
        axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/api/component/getSetupTabTitles`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({type: GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES,
                    payload: response
                });
            });
    }
}
```

this is my initial state on reducer :

```
export default {
    auth: {
        authenticated: (localStorage.getItem('laravel_user_token') !== null),
        userinfo: {
            name: null
        },
        error:""
    },
    comp: {
        openDrawerStatus: false, 
        setupTabTitles: null,
    }
};
```

and this is my reducer :

```
import {
    TOGGLE_DRAWER_IN_APPBAR,
    GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES,
} from '../constants/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';

const compReducer = (state = initialState.comp, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_DRAWER_IN_APPBAR:
            return objectAssign({}, state, {openDrawerStatus: action.openStatus});

        case GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES:
            console.log(action.payload.data);
            return objectAssign({}, state, {setupTabTitles: action.payload.data});

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default compReducer;
```

when i do console.log inside

> case GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES:

it show :

> Array[2]0:  0:Object 1:Object

On using `JSON.stringify()` it shows me `[{"tabTitle":"Events"},{"tabTitle":"Tasks"}]`

but my state (setupTabTitles) didn't change at all.

i do try this one :

```
case GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES:

            state.setupTabTitles.push(action.payload.data[0]);
            return state;
```

it work, but i don't want to direct change the state.

Comment: Try printing the state inside the `case GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES:` using `console.log(JSON.stringify(action.payload.data)` to see the nature of the data.  You could just `console.log(JSON.stringify(action.payload)` and show us the result.

Comment: @cdaiga result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(action.payload.data))` = `[{"tabTitle":"Events"},{"tabTitle":"Tasks"}]`

Comment: @cdaiga result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(action.payload));` = `{"data":[{"tabTitle":"Events"},{"tabTitle":"Tasks"}],"status":200,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"content-type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","cache-control":"private, must-revalidate"},"config":{"transformRequest":{},"transformResponse":{},"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"method":"get","url":"http://localhost:8000/api/component/getSetupTabTitles"},"request":{}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `import ojectAssign from 'object-assign';` when you make use of the current ES6 syntax in your code. You only need `Object.assign`. Also since your `action.data.payload` is an array and you need to append to an array you can use the spread operator like

```
      return { 
                ...state,
                setupTabTitles: [...state.setupTabTitles, action.payload.data]
             }
```

Also you need to initialise you  componentState to be an empty array and not null or undefined. Change that to below code

```
export default {
    auth: {
        authenticated: (localStorage.getItem('laravel_user_token') !== null),
        userinfo: {
            name: null
        },
        error:""
    },
    comp: {
        openDrawerStatus: false, 
        setupTabTitles: [],
    }
};
```

Try it like below

```
const compReducer = (state = initialState.comp, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_DRAWER_IN_APPBAR:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {openDrawerStatus: action.openStatus});

        case GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES:
            console.log(action.payload.data);
            return { 
                ...state,
                setupTabTitles: [...state.setupTabTitles, ...action.payload.data]
             }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

The syntax of `objectAssign` is different from what I use, you can see it **[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign)**

```js
var state = {
            openDrawerStatus: false, 
            setupTabTitles: [],
        }
var payload  = [{"tabTitle":"Events"},{"tabTitle":"Tasks"}]
console.log( { 
                    ...state,
                    setupTabTitles: [...state.setupTabTitles, ...payload]
                 });
```

Comment: i already use that one too. it doesn't work too @Shubham Khatri

Comment: @ukiyakimura your action.payload.data is an array and you are trying to assign that to an object .

Comment: i got this error : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.from (native)`

Comment: i still got an empty array. @Shubham Khatri

Comment: Can you post the code where you dispatch an action GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES and then print the response. Also I want  you to  `console.log({ 
                ...state,
                setupTabTitles: [...state.setupTabTitles, action.payload.data]
             });` and then return the same and tell me the result  of console.log.

Comment: when i do `console.log({ ...state, setupTabTitles: [...state.setupTabTitles, action.payload.data] });` . it return `Object {openDrawerStatus: false, setupTabTitles: Array[1]}`  i update the code above when i fire the action @Shubham Khatri

Comment: @ukiyakimura considering the fact that you get a response from console.log() as `Object {openDrawerStatus: false, setupTabTitles: Array[1]}` it means that array is updated and you are returnign the same thing. My concern is that after you fire an action, you are trying to immediately print the values and since it is not available yet its giving you an empty array. Check for that. Also I have updated my answer, you need to use spread operator in ...action.payload.data also. Added a snippet

Comment: I already found my problem. it's in my store. i already fix that and use the code you reference, it's already work. thx you so much @Shubham Khatri

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using ES6, you could just use the object spread operator and get rid of the `object-assign` library, it would be like this:

```
import {
    TOGGLE_DRAWER_IN_APPBAR,
    GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES,
} from '../constants/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

const compReducer = (state = initialState.comp, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_DRAWER_IN_APPBAR:
            return { ...state, openDrawerStatus: action.openStatus };
        case GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES:
            return { ...state, setupTabTitles: action.payload.data };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default compReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initial state, I would change `setupTabTitle` from `null` to an empty array `[]`:

```
setupTabTitles: [],
```

And in your reducer, append data to this array:

```
const compReducer = (state = initialState.comp, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...
        case GET_SETUP_TAB_TITLES:
            return { 
                ...state,
                setupTabTitles: [
                  ...state.setupTabTitles,
                  ...action.payload.data
                ]
             }
             ...
    }
};
```

Or if you don't want to append, just replace, I would do:

```
setupTabTitles: [
  ...action.payload.data
]
```

Comment: it return an empty array. @szymonm

Comment: Are you sure `action.payload.data` is in the right format? Can you paste the result of `console.log(action.payload.data)` here?